# Is a complex function continuous at a point if and only if it is entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

In $\mathbb{R}$, any *continuous* function $f(x), a<x<b$, has an antiderivative:
$$
F = \int_a^{x}f(t)dt,
$$
In $\mathbb{C}$, a function $f(z)$ has an antiderivative only if it is *entire* (based on my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong).

This difference between the existence of an antiderivative in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is the source of my question:

**My question is:** In $\mathbb{C}$, is a function continuous if and only if it is entire (or, at least, analytic in its domain)?

Comment: $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ is continuous, but not analytic.

Comment: @totoro Does it mean my assumption that a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ always has an anti-derivative is probably incorrect as well?

Comment: That's the content of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements)

Comment: @totoro ok so in $\mathbb{R}$, continuity is sufficient to guarantee the existence of an antiderivative. But it is not the case in $\mathbb{C}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, existence of complex derivative, and therefore, complex anti-derivative is a stronger condition. It turns out that the condition to have  complex anti-derivative is to have complex derivative in an open set.